# Excel - Max Date based on Criteria in Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, maxifs

In the table below, I'm trying to find the max date (most recent) based on the criteria "Major" for each facility. I tried using maxifs to no avail, and my table setup is different than any other post I've seen on here.

Example - the date I'm looking for on Facility 200 would be 7/7/2014.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/MATCH

```
=INDEX(D3:M3,MATCH("Major",D3:M3,0)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a one column stagger between max range and criteria range. In C3,

```
=maxifs(e3:m3, d3:l3, "major")
```

Or as an old fashioned array formula,

```
=max(if(d3:l3="major", e3:m3))
```

Comment: This method is detailed in example 2 within official Office [MAXIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - that worked great. I missed that when I searched for it before.